# how to make canvas fit to the max width of a modals column?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, canvas

I'm trying to make a modal with 2 columns. The first column with input text and the second will have a canvas image. I want to make the canvas fit the columns width and automatically add vertical scroll if the image is longer. My problem is that the modal automatically adjust it size if the child is bigger. And I don't want to put a fixed width in the column. I've tried clientHeight and clientWidth but it returns zero.

**CSS**

```
#container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#image {
  display: none;
}

#canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

**MODAL**

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="editModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Value</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="label_name" >Value</label>
                  <input class="form-control  form-control-sm" name="label_name" type="text" disabled value="Test Value"  >
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body" >
                  <img id="image" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Jz43RmrZ/moon.png">
                  <div id="container">
                    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function editFunc(id) {
  const container = document.getElementById('container');

  // Get the image element
  const image = document.getElementById('image');

  // Get the canvas element
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

  // Set the size of the canvas element to match the size of the image
  //canvas.width = containers.clientWidth;
  //canvas.height = containers.clientHeight;

  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;

  // Get the canvas context
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Draw the image on the canvas
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```